# Structs not working as expected in C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I have the following program, with the following output written in C.

I expect after prepending a value for my tail to be 40 and my head 30, but it is not.

Am I making a mistake with memory allocation of the structs or is it something less obvious than that?

I am using the GCC compiler on Mac OSX.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct LinkedListNode {
    int data;
    struct LinkedListNode *next;
};

struct LinkedList {
    int size;
    struct LinkedListNode *head;
    struct LinkedListNode *tail;
};

struct LinkedList create_linked_list(){
    struct LinkedList linkedList;

    linkedList.size = 0;
    linkedList.head = NULL;
    linkedList.tail = NULL;

    return linkedList;
}

struct LinkedList prepend(struct LinkedList *linkedList, int data){
    struct LinkedListNode linkedListNode;
    linkedListNode.data = data;
    linkedListNode.next = linkedList->head;

    linkedList->head = &linkedListNode;

    if(linkedList->tail == NULL){
        printf("Setting tail to: %d\n", data);
        linkedList->tail = &linkedListNode;
    }else{
        printf("The tail is: %d\n", linkedList->tail->data);
    }

    linkedList->size = linkedList->size + 1;

    return *linkedList;
}

int main(){
    struct LinkedList linkedList;
    linkedList = create_linked_list();

    linkedList = prepend(&linkedList, 40);

    struct LinkedListNode head = *linkedList.head;
    struct LinkedListNode tail = *linkedList.tail;

    printf("%d\n", head.data);
    printf("%d\n", tail.data);
    printf("%d\n", linkedList.size);

    linkedList = prepend(&linkedList, 30);

    head = *linkedList.head;
    tail = *linkedList.tail;

    printf("%d\n", head.data);
    printf("%d\n", tail.data);
    printf("%d\n", linkedList.size);
}
```

Output:

```
Setting tail to: 40
40
40
1
The tail is: 30
30
30
2
```

Comment: Please do not update your question to contain the result of an answer. That is what answers are for. By accepting an answer, you have already shown how to fix your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One major problem is here:

```
linkedList->head = &linkedListNode;
```

Here you make `linkedList->head` point to the location of the ***local*** variable `linkedListNode`. That variable will go out of scope once the function returns, and the pointer will become a *stray* pointer that you no longer can dereference without having [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The solution to this problem is to allocate the `LinkedListNode` structure *dynamically* using [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc).

Comment: Would this do it? `linkedListNode = *(struct LinkedListNode *)malloc(sizeof(linkedListNode));`

Comment: @JacobClark, `linkedListNode` must be a pointer. The snippet you provided will copy the contents of the heap-allocated struct to local variable, which is not what you want. `linkedListNode = malloc(sizeof(LinkedListNode))` is what you likely want.

Comment: Thanks! Updated my question with the solution. It was malloc :)

Comment: @n0rd He should rather start a habit of not turning questions into answers, as when the question is in fast the answer to a problem, where would then be the question? In the answer? ;-)